# Example for $J_{a \bullet b} (p) \neq J_a (b(p) )$ - Jacobian matrices

Tags: calculus, matrices, partial-derivative

I know that: $J_{a \bullet b} (p) \neq J_a (b(p) )$, even though I lack a good not too trivial example to compare $J_{a \bullet b} (p) $ and $J_a (b(p))$ and see that they different. 
I would be very happy, if someone could provide me a short one or give a reference to one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $a\bullet b$? If it is the composition of functions then it is $J_{a\bullet b}=J_a(b(p))J_b(p)$

Comment: Well, for instance $a=id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, and $b$ any differentiable map $\mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $k\neq n$, I guess.